# Javascript array traversal overwriting key values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, traversal

I have a hashmap that I have created to control the events for buttons. It is defined as so:

```
var Signage_Manager = {

init: function() {

    Signage_Manager.buttonActions.set_events();

},
buttonActions: {
    buttons: {

        '#add_product': {action: 'navigate', href: '/manager/add_product'},
        '.back_to_dashboard': {action: 'navigate', href: '/manager/dashboard'}

    },
    set_events: function() {
        for(var button in Signage_Manager.buttonActions.buttons){   
            if(Signage_Manager.buttonActions.buttons[button].action == 'navigate') {
                $(button).live('click', function() {
                    console.log(Signage_Manager.buttonActions.buttons[button].href);                                                 
                });
            }
            else {
                $(button).live('click', function() {
                    //
                    console.log('not navigate');                                                     
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
};
```

The problem is when I click the 'add_product' button, it tries to use the href '/manager/dashboard', instead of the '/manager/add_product' string that is in the defined row.

Can anyone offer a hand here?

Comment: Can you attach a sample html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of *closure* your live functions will close over the **same** button variable, which changes in every **iteration**. And so **at the end** all event handlers will use the same button: **the last one**. In order to keep the button name, you can create an **inner scope** for the event handlers so as to ensure that each function will have its **own** jQuery selector.

```
if (Signage_Manager.buttonActions.buttons[button].action == 'navigate') {
  (function(button) {
    $(button).live('click', function () {
      console.log(Signage_Manager.buttonActions.buttons[button].href);
    });
  })(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `live()` call you have a reference to the `button` variable of the outer scope. When you click a button and the anonymous function gets executed the loop has already finished so button equals the last element of the hash table. You have to store the hash table element for each button.

A possible solution, using the data() method, could be:

```
$(button).data("button", Signage_Manager.buttonActions.buttons[button]).live('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).data("button").href);                            
});
```